# Hbase 0.90.2 doesn't start

Tags: 11.04, hadoop

It seems that something was changed in 11.04 because HBase couldn't start on 11.04 from the default distribution, but works on 10.10.

here's the logs:

```
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.38-8-generic
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=sbos
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/sbos
2011-05-17 18:30:24,369 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/sbos/Downloads/hbase-0.90.2
2011-05-17 18:30:24,370 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=master:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:24,377 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-05-17 18:30:24,377 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:35778
2011-05-17 18:30:24,378 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-05-17 18:30:24,382 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:35778
2011-05-17 18:30:24,383 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog: Creating new log file: log.1
2011-05-17 18:30:24,431 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x12ffe5d64cb0000 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:35778
2011-05-17 18:30:24,431 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x12ffe5d64cb0000, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-05-17 18:30:24,477 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=Master, sessionId=malta:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: revision
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsUser
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsDate
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsUrl
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: date
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsRevision
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: user
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsVersion
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: url
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: version
2    011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: new MBeanInfo
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: new MBeanInfo
2011-05-17 18:30:24,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.metrics.MasterMetrics: Initialized
2011-05-17 18:30:24,500 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
2011-05-17 18:30:24,501 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-05-17 18:30:24,501 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-05-17 18:30:24,501 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:35779
2011-05-17 18:30:24,501 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:35779
2011-05-17 18:30:24,508 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x12ffe5d64cb0001 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:35779
2011-05-17 18:30:24,509 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x12ffe5d64cb0001, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-05-17 18:30:24,510 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0001 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase
2011-05-17 18:30:24,517 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0001 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/unassigned Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/unassigned
2011-05-17 18:30:24,525 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0001 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/rs Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/rs
2011-05-17 18:30:24,533 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0001 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/table
2011-05-17 18:30:24,548 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRpcMetrics: Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=HRegionServer, port=57656
2011-05-17 18:30:24,560 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User: Skipping login, not running on secure Hadoop
2011-05-17 18:30:24,562 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=regionserver:57656
2011-05-17 18:30:24,563 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-05-17 18:30:24,563 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-05-17 18:30:24,563 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:35780
2011-05-17 18:30:24,563 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:35780
2011-05-17 18:30:24,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ActiveMasterManager: Master=malta:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:24,575 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x12ffe5d64cb0002 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:35780
2011-05-17 18:30:24,576 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0002 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase
2011-05-17 18:30:24,576 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x12ffe5d64cb0002, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-05-17 18:30:24,584 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0002 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/unassigned Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/unassigned
2011-05-17 18:30:24,592 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0002 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/rs Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/rs
2011-05-17 18:30:24,602 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0002 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/table
2011-05-17 18:30:24,680 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
2011-05-17 18:30:24,680 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-05-17 18:30:24,681 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:35781
2011-05-17 18:30:24,681 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2    011-05-17 18:30:24,681 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:35781
2011-05-17 18:30:24,692 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x12ffe5d64cb0003 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:35781
2011-05-17 18:30:24,692 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x12ffe5d64cb0003, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-05-17 18:30:24,692 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0003 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase
2011-05-17 18:30:24,700 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0003 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/unassigned Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/unassigned
2011-05-17 18:30:24,708 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0003 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/rs Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/rs
2011-05-17 18:30:24,717 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x12ffe5d64cb0003 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/table
2011-05-17 18:30:24,733 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker: Starting catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@18330bf
2011-05-17 18:30:24,769 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Server active/primary master; malta:32910, sessionid=0x12ffe5d64cb0000, cluster-up flag was=false
2011-05-17 18:30:24,770 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=MASTER_OPEN_REGION-malta:32910, corePoolSize=5, maxPoolSize=5
2011-05-17 18:30:24,770 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=MASTER_CLOSE_REGION-malta:32910, corePoolSize=5, maxPoolSize=5
2011-05-17 18:30:24,771 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=MASTER_SERVER_OPERATIONS-malta:32910, corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize=3
2011-05-17 18:30:24,771 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=MASTER_META_SERVER_OPERATIONS-malta:32910, corePoolSize=5, maxPoolSize=5
2011-05-17 18:30:24,771 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-malta:32910, corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=1
2011-05-17 18:30:24,772 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LogCleaner: Add log cleaner in chain: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.TimeToLiveLogCleaner
2011-05-17 18:30:24,849 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker: Starting catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@24988707
2011-05-17 18:30:24,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher: globalMemStoreLimit=398.4m, globalMemStoreLimitLowMark=348.6m, maxHeap=995.9m
2011-05-17 18:30:24,854 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.PriorityCompactionQueue: Create PriorityCompactionQueue
2011-05-17 18:30:24,854 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Runs every 10000000ms
2011-05-17 18:30:24,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Attempting connect to Master server at malta:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:24,990 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2011-05-17 18:30:25,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Master isn't available yet, retrying
2011-05-17 18:30:25,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 60010
2011-05-17 18:30:25,056 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 60010 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 60010
2011-05-17 18:30:25,056 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 60010
2011-05-17 18:30:25,056 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2011-05-17 18:30:25,440 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
2011-05-17 18:30:25,440 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Started service threads
2011-05-17 18:30:26,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting on regionserver(s) to checkin
2011-05-17 18:30:28,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Attempting connect to Master server at malta:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:28,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Connected to master at malta:32910
2011-05-17 18:30:28,047 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Telling master at malta:32910 that we are up
2011-05-17 18:30:28,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Registering server=localhost,57656,1305642624559, regionCount=0, userLoad=false
2011-05-17 18:30:28,053 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Master passed us address to use. Was=malta:57656, Now=localhost:57656
2011-05-17 18:30:28,053 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Config from master: fs.default.name=file:///
2011-05-17 18:30:28,053 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Config from master: hbase.rootdir=file:///tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase
2011-05-17 18:30:28,055 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: logdir=file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57656,1305642624559
2011-05-17 18:30:28,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: HLog configuration: blocksize=32 MB, rollsize=30.4 MB, enabled=true, flushlogentries=1, optionallogflushinternal=1000ms
2011-05-17 18:30:28,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogWriter: syncFs -- HDFS-200 -- not available, dfs.support.append=false
2011-05-17 18:30:28,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: New hlog /tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57656,1305642624559/localhost%3A57656.1305642628057
2011-05-17 18:30:28,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: getNumCurrentReplicas--HDFS-826 not available; hdfs_out=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer@60a415a3, exception=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2011-05-17 18:30:28,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=RegionServer, sessionId=RegionServer:0;malta,57656,1305642624559 - already initialized
2011-05-17 18:30:28,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: new MBeanInfo
2011-05-17 18:30:28,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.RegionServerMetrics: Initialized
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_OPEN_REGION-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize=3
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_OPEN_ROOT-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=1
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_OPEN_META-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=1
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_CLOSE_REGION-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize=3
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_CLOSE_ROOT-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=1
2011-05-17 18:30:28,147 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.ExecutorService: Starting executor service name=RS_CLOSE_META-localhost,57656,1305642624559, corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=1
2011-05-17 18:30:28,168 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 60030
2011-05-17 18:30:28,168 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 60030 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 60030
2011-05-17 18:30:28,168 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 60030
2011-05-17 18:30:28,168 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2011-05-17 18:30:28,268 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60030
2011-05-17 18:30:28,303 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server Responder: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,303 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server listener on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 1 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,325 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 3 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,325 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 2 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,348 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 4 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 6 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 5 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,359 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 8 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 9 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 0 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,389 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 1 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,399 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 2 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 3 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,419 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 4 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,429 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 5 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,430 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 7 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,431 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 6 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 7 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 8 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:28,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Serving as localhost,57656,1305642624559, RPC listening on /127.0.1.1:57656, sessionid=0x12ffe5d64cb0002
2011-05-17 18:30:28,441 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting on regionserver(s) count to settle; currently=1
2011-05-17 18:30:28,442 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Allocating LruBlockCache with maximum size 199.2m
2011-05-17 18:30:28,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 9 on 57656: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:29,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Finished waiting for regionserver count to settle; count=1, sleptFor=4500
2011-05-17 18:30:29,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Exiting wait on regionserver(s) to checkin; count=1, stopped=false, count of regions out on cluster=0
2011-05-17 18:30:29,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem: Log folder file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57656,1305642624559 belongs to an existing region server
2011-05-17 18:30:29,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem: Log folder file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674 doesn't belong to a known region server, splitting
2011-05-17 18:30:29,948 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Splitting 1 hlog(s) in file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674
2011-05-17 18:30:29,949 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Writer thread Thread[WriterThread-0,5,main]: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:29,952 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Splitting hlog 1 of 1: file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180, length=0
2011-05-17 18:30:29,952 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Running on HDFS without append enabled may result in data loss
2011-05-17 18:30:29,952 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: File file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180 might be still open, length is 0
2011-05-17 18:30:29,956 WARN org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker: Problem opening checksum file: file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180.  Ignoring exception: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.openFile(SequenceFile.java:1444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader$WALReader.openFile(SequenceFileLogReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader$WALReader.<init>(SequenceFileLogReader.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader.init(SequenceFileLogReader.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog.getReader(HLog.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.getReader(HLogSplitter.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.parseHLog(HLogSplitter.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLog(HLogSplitter.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLog(HLogSplitter.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLogAfterStartup(MasterFileSystem.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:193)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2011-05-17 18:30:29,957 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader: Error while trying to get accurate file length.  Truncation / data loss may occur if RegionServers die.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.getFileLength()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader$WALReader$WALReaderFSDataInputStream.getPos(SequenceFileLogReader.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader$WALReader.<init>(SequenceFileLogReader.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.SequenceFileLogReader.init(SequenceFileLogReader.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog.getReader(HLog.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.getReader(HLogSplitter.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.parseHLog(HLogSplitter.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLog(HLogSplitter.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLog(HLogSplitter.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLogAfterStartup(MasterFileSystem.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:193)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2011-05-17 18:30:29,959 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Could not open file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180 for reading. File is emptyjava.io.EOFException
2011-05-17 18:30:29,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Writer thread Thread[WriterThread-1,5,main]: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:29,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Writer thread Thread[WriterThread-2,5,main]: starting
2011-05-17 18:30:29,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Archived processed log file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.logs/localhost,57701,1305642579674/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180 to file:/tmp/hbase-sbos/hbase/.oldlogs/localhost%3A57701.1305642583180
2011-05-17 18:30:29,964 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Waiting for split writer threads to finish
```

full logs are here: http://pastebin.com/1A2YmkQZ

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'd found the [solution](http://blog.sbos.in/post/5603105690/running-hbase-on-new-ubuntu-11-04)

Answer (score 3):

OP posted:

> I'd found the [solution](http://blog.sbos.in/post/5603105690/running-hbase-on-new-ubuntu-11-04). Check the:

```
${ping `hostname`}.
```

> If it send pings to 127.0.1.1 and you actually expect that the address should be 127.0.0.1, that’s the problem. Fix it, for example, by removing record for 127.0.1.1 from your /etc/hosts.